# Axios error when on run generate Nuxt project

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

Building my nuxt project using:

```
npm run build
```

which completes. I then:

```
npm run generate
```

and get the following errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix these?

```
ERROR  Request failed with status code 403

at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

✔ Client-side fallback created: 200.html
✔ Static manifest generated

ERROR  Request failed with status code 500

at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

ERROR  Request failed with status code 500

at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: `npm run generate` is for full-static generation **only**. `npm run build` is for all the other targets. You need to tell us what you're actually targeting here. And you also should only use one, not both. More details here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands/#list-of-commands

Answer (score 0):

I stopped with similar problem. I make online store with nuxt, mongodb and my own api. Everything works fine in npm run dev. There is many info that server and axios doesn't enable during generate.
In dynamic routes such as category/toys I use axios call for fetching data from mongo. Generate block in nuxt.config.js include route func for this. But pages like category/[path] can't generate with error on steps when axios try to make call.
Who's know what happens?